# Why binding controllers models doesn't work for nested properties of service model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Here is fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nqscd124/). It seem for me that implicit $watch doesn't work in simpleAlertCtrl. But i can explicitly point which service model property need to  extract,  when model will change. Could you provide more complex explanation, why `simpleAlertCtrl` binding doesn't work ?!

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">  
<br/><div id="alert" ng-show="show" ng-controller="watchAlertCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        Alert text: {{message}}
    </div>     
</div>    
<br/><div id="alert" ng-show="show" ng-controller="simpleAlertCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        Alert text: {{message}}
    </div>     
</div>  
<br/><div ng-controller="anotherCtrl">
    <button ng-click="Inc()">Increment</button>
</div>
</body>
```

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.factory('sharingData', function () {
    var alert = {};
    alert.show = true;
    alert.message = " ";
    return { alert: alert };
});

app.controller("watchAlertCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   
    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return sharingData.alert;
    }, function(value){
        console.log(value);
        $scope.message = value.message;
        $scope.show = value.show;
    },true);
});

app.controller("simpleAlertCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {   
    $scope.message = sharingData.alert.message;
    $scope.show = sharingData.alert.show;
});

app.controller("anotherCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.Inc = function (){
        $scope.count ++ ;
        sharingData.alert.message = $scope.count.toString();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answer based on your question and your fiddle's example*

First of all, data bound to `$scope` will be double bound only if **the content referenced changes**. For instance in your case, in `anotherController` if you do

```
sharingData.alert.message = 'some new value';
```

then in `simpleAlertCtrl` the `$scope.message` will still be bound to the old value: because the reference of the string variable won't have changed in this other controller. You'd rather bind an object whose reference won't change:

```
app.controller("alertCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {
  $scope.alert = sharingData.alert;
});
```

On the other hand, if you want to watch an expression, look for that expression. For instance in `anotherController`, when an event occurs, you're either looking for `text` expression in its scope or a function that returns `$scope.text` (which corresponds to the input of the user)

```
app.controller("anotherCtrl", function($scope, sharingData) {
    $scope.$watch('text', function(value){
        sharingData.alert.message = value;
        sharingData.alert.show = true;
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqscd124/1/